# Django: Using SSL (https) scheme for static content served from sub-domain

Tags: django, ssl

My site uses a sub-domain to serve static content (static.example.com). Therefore, `STATIC_URL` must be an absolute URL. The `STATIC_URL`, `{% get_static_prefix %}`, `MEDIA_URL`, etc. should use the `https://` scheme when the request is secure.

**What is the typical way to reference the the static content URL in a template with a scheme that matches the request?**

If there isn't anything built-in I'll just replace django.core.context_processors.static with my own context processor that uses is_secure(). But, I figured this is common enough that there must be a "conventional" way of dealing with this. Perhaps this *is* how people normally do it?

I have Django 1.3/nginx/mod_wsgi configured properly such that Django knows when the request is over SSL using request.is_secure().

I want to avoid scheme-less URLs (due to IE double-download) and middleware (seems like overkill).

Comment: I understand the sentiment, but I still think scheme-less URLs are the best way to go. Anything else is overkill. The double-download only affects stylesheets, only in IE7/8 and then only on the first load. After the cache kicks in, there's no more issues. It's really not that big of a deal performance-wise, and I tend to take the view that IE users get what they deserve. We already have to load extra stuff for them anyways to gain feature parity with modern browsers.

Comment: "IE users get what they deserve" - Haha. Thanks for the comments. I just may go with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the scheme-less URLs for `STATIC_URL` and `MEDIA_URL`.